# ffmpeg seems to output a video with a wrong codec?

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg

I´m using `ffmpeg` with flutter and I create a video from a lot of images. The problem: `ffmpeg` seems to not create a video with a right codec or something else.... please check my description below for concrete informations.

First the code parts:

**Creating video from images**

`-r $settings_fps -i $tempPath/img%04d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -y -an -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -shortest  $tempPath/$videoFileName.mp4`

**Adding audio to the created video**

`-i ${finalSong.path} -i $videoPath -c:a aac -shortest $tempPath/$newVideoFileName.mp4`

**This is my video output from console on creating this video:**

```
flutter: ffmpeg version git-2020-01-25-fd11dd500 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk --prefix=/Users/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/ios-arm64-apple-darwin/ffmpeg --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8 --target-os=darwin --ar=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar --cc=clang --cxx=clang++ --as='/Users/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/.tmp/gas-preprocessor.pl -arch aarch64 -- clang -arch arm64 -target aarch64-ios-darwin -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mcpu=generic -DMOBILE_FFMPEG_ARM64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fstrict-aliasing -fembed-bitcode -DIOS -DMOBILE_FFMPEG_BUILD_DATE=20200125 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -Oz -miphoneos-version-min=12.1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include' --ranlib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib --strip=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip --enable-neon --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-small --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=fbdev --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --disable-sdl2 --enable-zlib --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-coreimage --enable-bzlib --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfoundation --enable-iconv
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 65.102 / 58. 65.102
  libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 70.101 /  7. 70.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
Input #0, mp3, from '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AEEF7BB8-36F3-4ECD-824B-B294E9DF7294/Library/Caches/melodic_slow.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : LAME 32bits version 3.99.5 (http://lame.sf.net)
    TLEN            : 134072
  Duration: 00:02:14.11, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AEEF7BB8-36F3-4ECD-824B-B294E9DF7294/Library/Caches/Memories_163dfbf0-f4cf-11ea-86c6-cd08c5621e56.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10069 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj422p(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 10065 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (mp3float) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
using SAR=1/1
using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
profile High 4:2:2, level 4.0, 4:2:2, 8-bit
264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=9 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AEEF7BB8-36F3-4ECD-824B-B294E9DF7294/Library/Caches/Memories_191007b0-f4cf-11ea-9024-c9fcef51db39.mp4':
  Metadata:
    TLEN            : 134072
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj422p(pc, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.65.102 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.65.102 aac
frame=   47 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
frame=   61 fps= 49 q=28.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:00.23 bitrate=9033.3kbits/s speed=0.187x
frame=   73 fps= 42 q=28.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:00.71 bitrate=5827.4kbits/s speed=0.411x
frame=   84 fps= 21 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3418kB time=00:00:03.50 bitrate=7986.4kbits/s speed=0.856x
video:3359kB audio:55kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.117042%
frame I:1     Avg QP:22.78  size:170700
frame P:22    Avg QP:23.95  size: 83595
frame B:61    Avg QP:28.22  size: 23428
consecutive B-frames:  2.4%  2.4%  0.0% 95.2%
mb I  I16..4:  1.8% 97.3%  0.9%
mb P  I16..4:  0.4% 13.4%  1.0%  P16..4: 39.0% 21.7% 14.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:10.3%
mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  2.4%  0.2%  B16..8: 27.0%  6.3%  2.1%  direct: 2.4%  skip:59.5%  L0:39.3% L1:47.8% BI:12.9%
8x8 transform intra:91.6% inter:83.1%
coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 88.4% 97.3% 40.9% inter: 21.1% 26.6% 1.7%
i16 v,h,dc,p: 18% 27%  7% 48%
i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 18% 16%  5%  8%  8%  9%  7%  9%
i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 16% 13%  7% 11% 10% 10%  7%  8%
i8c dc,h,v,p: 41% 19% 28% 12%
Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
ref P L0: 53.9% 22.4% 18.3%  5.4%
ref B L0: 86.7%  9.9%  3.4%
ref B L1: 96.1%  3.9%
kb/s:7860.37
Qavg: 149.884
flutter: ffmpeg version git-2020-01-25-fd11dd500
flutter:  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
flutter:
flutter:   built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
flutter:   configuration: --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk --prefix=/Users/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/ios-arm64-apple-darwin/ffmpeg --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8 --target-os=darwin --ar=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar --cc=clang --cxx=clang++ --as='/Users/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/.tmp/gas-preprocessor.pl -arch aarch64 -- clang -arch arm64 -target aarch64-ios-darwin -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mcpu=generic -DMOBILE_FFMPEG_ARM64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fstrict-aliasing -fembed-bitcode -DIOS -DMOBILE_FFMPEG_BUILD_DATE=20200125 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -Oz -miphoneos-version-min=12.1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include' --ranlib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib --strip=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip --enable-neon --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-small --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=fbdev --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --disable-sdl2 --enable-zlib --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-coreimage --enable-bzlib --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfoundation --enable-iconv
flutter:   libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
flutter:   libavcodec     58. 65.102 / 58. 65.102
flutter:   libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
flutter:   libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
flutter:   libavfilter     7. 70.101 /  7. 70.101
flutter:   libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
flutter:   libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
flutter: Input #0, image2, from '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AEEF7BB8-36F3-4ECD-824B-B294E9DF7294/Library/Caches/img%04d.jpg':
flutter:   Duration:
flutter: 00:00:03.40
flutter: , start:
flutter: 0.000000
flutter: , bitrate:
flutter: N/A
flutter:
flutter:     Stream #0:0
flutter: : Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9]
flutter: ,
flutter: 25 fps,
flutter: 25 tbr,
flutter: 25 tbn,
flutter: 25 tbc
flutter:
flutter: Stream mapping:
flutter:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
flutter:  (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
flutter:
flutter: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
flutter: sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
flutter: using SAR=1/1
flutter: using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
flutter: profile High 4:2:2, level 4.0, 4:2:2, 8-bit
flutter: 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=9 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
flutter: Output #0, mp4, to '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AEEF7BB8-36F3-4ECD-824B-B294E9DF7294/Library/Caches/Memories_f578a1c0-f4d0-11ea-9e60-5b43394b2511.mp4':
flutter:   Metadata:
flutter:     encoder         :
flutter: Lavf58.35.101
flutter:
flutter:     Stream #0:0
flutter: : Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj422p(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1
flutter: ,
flutter: 24 fps,
flutter: 12288 tbn,
flutter: 24 tbc
flutter:
flutter:     Metadata:
flutter:       encoder         :
flutter: Lavc58.65.102 libx264
flutter:
flutter:     Side data:
flutter:
flutter: cpb:
flutter: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0
flutter: vbv_delay: N/A
flutter:
flutter: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A
flutter: frame=   47 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
flutter: frame=   60 fps= 53 q=28.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:00.16 bitrate=12579.1kbits/s speed=0.147x
flutter: frame=   72 fps= 43 q=28.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:00.66 bitrate=9436.6kbits/s speed=0.401x
flutter: frame=   84 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:01.16 bitrate=8987.5kbits/s speed=0.527x
flutter: frame=   85 fps= 19 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4334kB time=00:00:03.41 bitrate=10391.1kbits/s speed=0.773x
flutter: video:4332kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:
flutter: 0.043800%
flutter:
flutter: frame I:1     Avg QP:22.19  size:178746
flutter: frame P:21    Avg QP:23.69  size:106999
flutter: frame B:63    Avg QP:28.13  size: 31899
flutter: consecutive B-frames:  1.2%  0.0%  0.0% 98.8%
flutter: mb I  I16..4:  2.4% 97.0%  0.6%
flutter: mb P  I16..4:  0.7% 38.2%  0.8%  P16..4: 22.6% 19.2% 15.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 3.3%
flutter: mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  6.7%  0.2%  B16..8: 24.6%  8.6%  3.0%  direct: 4.2%  skip:52.5%  L0:47.8% L1:36.8% BI:15.4%
flutter: 8x8 transform intra:95.8% inter:86.8%
flutter: coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 89.3% 95.1% 22.5% inter: 26.3% 28.9% 3.0%
flutter: i16 v,h,dc,p: 20% 33% 22% 24%
flutter: i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 24% 33%  3%  4%  3%  4%  4%  5%
flutter: i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 20% 16%  6% 10%  7%  9%  6%  7%
flutter: i8c dc,h,v,p: 44% 22% 29%  5%
flutter: Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
flutter: ref P L0: 43.8% 18.2% 23.0% 15.0%
flutter: ref B L0: 69.6% 22.3%  8.1%
flutter: ref B L1: 86.1% 13.9%
flutter: kb/s:10018.70
flutter: Video erfolgreich erstellt
flutter: Ja. Video existiert im Pfad!
flutter: ffmpeg version git-2020-01-25-fd11dd500
flutter:  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
flutter:
flutter:   built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
flutter:   configuration: --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk --prefix=/Users/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/ios-arm64-apple-darwin/ffmpeg --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8 --target-os=darwin --ar=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar --cc=clang --cxx=clang++ --as='/Users/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/.tmp/gas-preprocessor.pl -arch aarch64 -- clang -arch arm64 -target aarch64-ios-darwin -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mcpu=generic -DMOBILE_FFMPEG_ARM64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fstrict-aliasing -fembed-bitcode -DIOS -DMOBILE_FFMPEG_BUILD_DATE=20200125 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -Oz -miphoneos-version-min=12.1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include' --ranlib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib --strip=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip --enable-neon --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-small --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=fbdev --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --disable-sdl2 --enable-zlib --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-coreimage --enable-bzlib --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfoundation --enable-iconv
flutter:   libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
flutter:   libavcodec     58. 65.102 / 58. 65.102
flutter:   libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
flutter:   libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
flutter:   libavfilter     7. 70.101 /  7. 70.101
flutter:   libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
flutter:   libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
flutter: Input #0, mp3, from '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AEEF7BB8-36F3-4ECD-824B-B294E9DF7294/Library/Caches/melodic_slow.mp3':
flutter:   Metadata:
flutter:     encoder         :
flutter: LAME 32bits version 3.99.5 (http://lame.sf.net)
flutter:
flutter:     TLEN            :
flutter: 134072
flutter:
flutter:   Duration:
flutter: 00:02:14.11
flutter: , start:
flutter: 0.025057
flutter: , bitrate:
flutter: 320 kb/s
flutter:
flutter:     Stream #0:0
flutter: : Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
flutter:
flutter:     Metadata:
flutter:       encoder         :
flutter: LAME3.99r
flutter:
flutter: Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AEEF7BB8-36F3-4ECD-824B-B294E9DF7294/Library/Caches/Memories_f578a1c0-f4d0-11ea-9e60-5b43394b2511.mp4':
flutter:   Metadata:
flutter:     major_brand     :
flutter: isom
flutter:
flutter:     minor_version   :
flutter: 512
flutter:
flutter:     compatible_brands:
flutter: isomiso2avc1mp41
flutter:
flutter:     encoder         :
flutter: Lavf58.35.101
flutter:
flutter:   Duration:
flutter: 00:00:03.54
flutter: , start:
flutter: 0.000000
flutter: , bitrate:
flutter: 10023 kb/s
flutter:
flutter:     Stream #1:0
flutter: (und)
flutter: : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj422p(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 10020 kb/s
flutter: ,
flutter: 24 fps,
flutter: 24 tbr,
flutter: 12288 tbn,
flutter: 48 tbc
flutter:  (default)
flutter:
flutter:     Metadata:
flutter:       handler_name    :
flutter: VideoHandler
flutter:
flutter: Stream mapping:
flutter:   Stream #1:0 -> #0:0
flutter:  (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
flutter:
flutter:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:1
flutter:  (mp3 (mp3float) -> aac (native))
flutter:
flutter: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
flutter: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
flutter: sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
flutter: using SAR=1/1
flutter: using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
flutter: profile High 4:2:2, level 4.0, 4:2:2, 8-bit
flutter: 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=9 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
flutter: Output #0, mp4, to '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AEEF7BB8-36F3-4ECD-824B-B294E9DF7294/Library/Caches/Memories_f81f09a0-f4d0-11ea-983d-0b683ab874e3.mp4':
flutter:   Metadata:
flutter:     TLEN            :
flutter: 134072
flutter:
flutter:     encoder         :
flutter: Lavf58.35.101
flutter:
flutter:     Stream #0:0
flutter: (und)
flutter: : Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj422p(pc, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1
flutter: ,
flutter: 24 fps,
flutter: 12288 tbn,
flutter: 24 tbc
flutter:  (default)
flutter:
flutter:     Metadata:
flutter:       handler_name    :
flutter: VideoHandler
flutter:
flutter:       encoder         :
flutter: Lavc58.65.102 libx264
flutter:
flutter:     Side data:
flutter:
flutter: cpb:
flutter: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0
flutter: vbv_delay: N/A
flutter:
flutter:     Stream #0:1
flutter: : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
flutter:
flutter:     Metadata:
flutter:       encoder         :
flutter: Lavc58.65.102 aac
flutter:
flutter: frame=   47 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
flutter: frame=   61 fps= 57 q=28.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:00.23 bitrate=9033.3kbits/s speed=0.218x
flutter: frame=   74 fps= 46 q=28.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:00.78 bitrate=7969.6kbits/s speed=0.489x
flutter: frame=   85 fps= 22 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3440kB time=00:00:03.55 bitrate=7933.2kbits/s speed=0.902x
flutter: video:3380kB audio:56kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:
flutter: 0.117084%
flutter:
flutter: frame I:1     Avg QP:22.68  size:174045
flutter: frame P:22    Avg QP:23.88  size: 84065
flutter: frame B:62    Avg QP:28.21  size: 23184
flutter: consecutive B-frames:  1.2%  4.7%  0.0% 94.1%
flutter: mb I  I16..4:  2.0% 97.3%  0.7%
flutter: mb P  I16..4:  0.4% 13.4%  0.9%  P16..4: 39.3% 21.6% 14.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 9.7%
flutter: mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  2.4%  0.2%  B16..8: 26.7%  6.3%  2.0%  direct: 2.5%  skip:59.8%  L0:41.1% L1:45.7% BI:13.1%
flutter: 8x8 transform intra:91.8% inter:83.1%
flutter: coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 88.3% 97.2% 41.4% inter: 21.0% 26.5% 1.7%
flutter: i16 v,h,dc,p: 18% 25%  5% 52%
flutter: i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 19% 16%  5%  8%  8%  9%  7%  9%
flutter: i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 16% 13%  7% 12%  9% 10%  7%  8%
flutter: i8c dc,h,v,p: 41% 19% 28% 12%
flutter: Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
flutter: ref P L0: 53.4% 22.2% 18.9%  5.5%
flutter: ref B L0: 86.6% 10.3%  3.2%
flutter: ref B L1: 95.8%  4.2%
flutter: kb/s:7817.54
flutter: Qavg: 149.529
flutter: Speichern mit GallerySaver: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AEEF7BB8-36F3-4ECD-824B-B294E9DF7294/Library/Caches/Memories_f81f09a0-f4d0-11ea-983d-0b683ab874e3.mp4
flutter: Speichern mit GallerySaver nicht erfolgreich
```

In general the created video works, but: If i try to save it as video with flutter `gallery_saver` to the device, this video will not saved. Other videos for example works well. But not the created with `ffmpeg`.

Can you find any reason for this in the ffmpeg output log? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Videos for web playback usually require chroma sampling to be 4:2:0. FFmpeg, by default, will try to preserve the source sampling scheme, so your output is 4:2:2 (see `yuvj422p` in the output stream).

Use for step 1,

`-r $settings_fps -i $tempPath/img%04d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -y -an -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -pix_fmt yuv420p $tempPath/$videoFileName.mp4`

And in step 2, avoid re-encoding video

`-i ${finalSong.path} -i $videoPath -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest $tempPath/$newVideoFileName.mp4`